# Fix Header and Footer while doing Routing in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want header and footer to be fixed while doing routing

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainPageComponent,
    children: [{
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'flex',
        component: FlexComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'jquery',
        component: JqueryComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'table',
        component: TableComponent
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: AboutComponent
  }
];
```

Above code is the have all the components and also included header and footer component.
this is a appmodule.ts. 
here i want to navigate to a different pages with fixed header and footer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [body content has to be update without header and footer change and no page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652374/body-content-has-to-be-update-without-header-and-footer-change-and-no-page-refre)

Comment: You should divide your template into 3 piece. In your navigation event, only change your template body context... For technically, you can easily find examples everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows

in app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

If don't want to have header and footer has separate component you can do it as below

```
<header code>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your component tree, you will have to put the header and footer in the main page component. This would make them fixed while routing